# Migrating away from Typescript in a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've done some googling, and haven't found a solid answer. In fact, I keep finding the exact opposite answer to my question (i.e., how to migrate TO TypeScript rather than from). As a TS newbie, I'm trying to consider the pros/cons of using it to pitch it to my org. My main question:

If we did adopt TS, what is the level of effort of removing it from a React project if we change our minds later?

My understanding is that TS transpiles to JS. If we wanted to switch to JS later on, we could simply take those transpiled JS files, check them into source, and remove the TS transpiler and files - no more TS. However, React itself has its own conventions that aren't plain JS, so I believe the transpiled files will be JS rather than JSX. Is there a method of transpiling React with TS to React directly that's as effortless as going directly to JS?

Comment: You can set ```jsx``` to "preserve" in your ```tsconfig.json``` file. Then when you compile the TS files, the output will retain all of the JSX syntax without the TS-only portions.

Comment: @ChrisB. that's perfect. thank you so much. if you want to write an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think using the transpiled files as your source files will be a very good idea. I believe typescript does various transformation that aren't the most human readable thing.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there another option, or just manual? I saw some library on GitHub that I’m not finding anymore, but it sounded like it wouldn’t work with React anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to remove typescript from your project?

Comment: Transpiled JS files are readable, barely and very much garbled so you wouldn't want to have to maintain them as if they were JavaScript.

Comment: @bryan60 i'm the minority in my org advocating for it. and front-end tech seems to change particularly fast. i'd like to be able to demonstrate that we aren't bound to this if it no longer makes sense to use it in the future.

Comment: @QuentinUK i appreciate the input. alex mentioned that as well, but i'm still unclear on whether there's an alternate way to remove typescript (aside manually doing it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, you can set `jsx: "preserve"` as an option in your TS configuration file, which will make the compiler forego transpiling the JSX into regular JS and output .jsx files you can use. Happy to help!

Answer (score -1):

the easiest way is to create a new project

steps to do this.

run tsc
delete node modules folder

use your terminal to delete all ts files
exp: rm -r **/**.ts or **/**/.tsx

copy the js code to a new react project